# input not adding class when focused

Tags: jquery

I have this **extremely** simple click event, where if the `input` has been focused, it is supposed to add a class to said `input`.

However, it doesn't want to add the class. I have been sure to include the **jQuery** library, but nothing happens.

**jQuery**:

```
$("body").on("click", function(){
    if($("input").is(":focus")){
        $(this).addClass("highlight-input");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight-input");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to check if all the inputs in your page are focused? Only one element can have focus. This will **always** be false.

Comment: Instead of jQuery use CSS `: focus`

Comment: @Tushar focus and hover are completely different...

Comment: Yes. I mean focus

Comment: @Tushar oh haha! for various reasons, I can't :/

Comment: @Caelan., A vote on my answer will be appreciated as well :) Thanks!

Comment: @Dekel already have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input").on("focus", function () {
    $(this).addClass("highlight-input");
  }).on("blur", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight-input");
  });
});
```

Comment: Already tried this, but I'll try it again with your code.. one moment

Comment: @Caelan. Works?

Comment: @Caelan. http://jsbin.com/zasihoxido/edit?html,css,js,output Same code. Works for me.

Comment: Tried this again, but it seemed to work only with your code.. Very strange haha. thanks :)

Comment: @Caelan. Merry Christmas.. `:D`

Answer (score 2):

In your code - `this` denotes the `body` element, so when you use `$(this).addClass("highlight-input");` you add the `highlight-input` class to the `body` element.

```js
$("body").on("click", function(){
    if($("input").is(":focus")){
      debugger;
      $(this).addClass("highlight-input");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight-input");
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight-input {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

> This is more likely what you are looking for:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).addClass("highlight-input");
}).on('blur', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("highlight-input");
});
```

```css
.highlight-input {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: Adds class to body! :(

Comment: Correct. I said it works, but I'm not sure this is what he was looking :) read carefully.

Comment: I read carefully: `it is supposed to add a class to said input.`